# How do I set alerts based on events in my Dataflow pipelines?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'd like to be able to take events like errors in my logs and set threshold-based alerts to notify me when anomalous behavior occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, visit the [Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/) page and click the "Create logs-based metric" button on the far right.  This will prompt you to enable the [Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/) API.

[image]

After doing this, return to the same page, where this button will allow you to create a metric name and description based on the current filter.

[image]

After creating such a metric, go to Dashboards & alerts, and click "Create Policy"

[image]

After entering a policy name, you can select Log Metrics as the resource type:

[image]

After clicking "Next", you should be able to select and configure an alert based on your "user/" metric:

[image]

Comment: What should the Threshold field look like? Can I have it be 0?

Comment: It depends on how noisy you can tolerate the alert being.  I would experiment with a few different values.